# Trigger server side event form child page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stuck with a issue where i need to trigger server side event

Hi have page with Index.aspx ,under same page i have some link tag if you click on link it will call another page DisplayContent.aspx within specifed contentpanel.

I want some server side event from DisplayContent.aspx using button,if i click on Button it is hitting parent page Index.aspx page .have any idea why is this happing.

```
<script>
(function(){with (this[2]) {with (this[1]) {with (this[0]){return function(event) {javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$FragmentContent$btnSend$field&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))
</script>
```

I think problem is Calling `"WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions"`

Comment: Sorry, but your question is really unclear.  Are you saying you want to press a button on index.aspx, but navigate to DisplayContent.aspx and trigger a button event on that page instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebMethod to do so. Follow the steps

1) Create a new page and add script manager in it (check if it is not already added in master page)

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
```

2) Add a server side function with annotation

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string callFunction(string words)
    {
        return "Your string was '" + words + "'";
    }
```

3) Add the following html controls in you aspx page

```
<div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtWords" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCall" OnClientClick="callServerFunction();return false;"
            Text="Submit" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

4) Add javascript function to call this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function callServerFunction() {
            var txtWords = document.getElementById('txtWords').value;
            PageMethods.callFunction(txtWords, OnSuccess, OnFailure);
        }
        //prompt success message..
        function OnSuccess(result) {
            if (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        }
        //prompt error message..
        function OnFailure(error) {
            if (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Try it in a separate page and then modify it according to your need.

Comment: Sorry i think you given a correct answer if that is the situation my problem is 
I will first navigate to Index.aspx page it is fully loaded and done.
In the same page i have a update panel to display a data from DisplayContent.aspx page for that i am calling a ajax method which will be bindeed with anchor tag in the Index.aspx page.

Comment: Ignore above comment
Sorry i think you dint got my question.
I will first navigate to Index.aspx page it is fully loaded and done.
In the same page i have a update panel to display a data from DisplayContent.aspx page for that i am calling a ajax method which will be binded with anchor tag in the Index.aspx page.
Since DisplayContent is displayed in index with partial post back ,if i add any button in the DisplayContent.aspx page and try to call a server side event means i am getting  error & and server side event is not calling.
is this clear i think.

Comment: First of all, test a simple form according to the steps in answer. If it is working then go ahead and try contentpanel (or page within page).